# Align arrow using its midpoint

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

I am displaying arrows between three equations. I am using align to line up the "lesser than"-sign, but I would like the arrows to be lined up as well. And, well, they are, but they are lined up at their starting point - how can I make them line up at the midpoint?

```
\begin{align*}
\ln(x) & < x \\
& \Longleftrightarrow \\
x & < e^{x} \\
& \Longleftrightarrow \\
x^{\frac{1}{x}} & < e
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Comment: Wrong, it's a supercool site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like this kind of formulas, but here it is; I make the double arrow the same width as the relation symbol (sticking out on either side), taking also into account the spacing around the relation symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % also loads amsmath
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand{\myiff}{\mathmakebox[\widthof{${}={}$}]{\Longleftrightarrow}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\log x & < x \\
& \myiff \\
x & < e^{x} \\
& \myiff \\
x^{\frac{1}{x}} & < e
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I *don't* apologize for having changed `\ln(x)` to the more traditional `\log x`. `;-)`

Comment: Great answer! I'd just like to know which of the two packages includes what. Also, why don't you like this kind of formula? How should I do it in your opinion? :)

Comment: @Vincent I generally dislike using `\Leftrightarrow` or similar symbols. Just personal preference; I normally use “if and only if” (completely spelled out).

Answer (score 0):

You also might try the `\ArrowBetweenLines` command from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % also loads amsmath
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\myiff}{\ArrowBetweenLines[{\scalebox{1}[1.25]{$ \Updownarrow $}}] }

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
    & & \log x & < x \\
  \myiff & &
  x & < e^{x} \\
  \myiff & &
  x^{\frac{1}{x}} & < e
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Changing the definition of `\myfill` to:

```
\newcommand{\myiff}{\ArrowBetweenLines[\Longleftrightarrow]}
```

you get horizontal arrows between equations:

[image]